# jQuery datatable - change cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm hoping someone can help me with this issue.
I am looking at a legacy application with the older version of datatables.net
It uses the function to populate the datatable and add colour to the row based on a returned name.
The code below works.

```
$(function () {

$("#ProfileTable").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bFilter": false, //Hide the search box
    "bInfo": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "sAjaxSource": 'DataTableHandler.ashx?dataTableId=ProfileTable',
    "aoColumns": [  //aoColumns defines the properties of the table columns
                    {
                        "mDataProp": "Name",
                        "fnRender": function (o) {
                            return SetToolTip(o);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "mDataProp": "DollarValue",
                        "fnRender": function (o) {
                            return accounting.formatMoney(dollarValue);
                        }
                        ,
                        "bUseRendered": false,
                        "sClass": "dataTableTextAlignRight"
                    }
    ],
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

        //Highlight the row colors based on the Name.  It must be identical to what is being retrieved from the database
        var columnData = aData["Name"];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = columnData;

        if (div.innerText == "TOYS" {
            $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#E0E0E0');
        }

        if (div.innerText == "LOST TOYS" ) {
            $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#BDBDBD');
        }
    }
 }
```

What i'm having trouble with is:  If the Name = "LOST TOYS" and the DollarValue = 0 then change the DollarValue to display as an empty string (i.e. no value displayed in the cell).

I have looked at using fnUpdate but i can't get it to read the correct row and column.  It comes back with "undefined".

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a brain fart. 
The code goes to server side to get the data.

Here's the link to the information:[Datatables forum posting about server side source](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8516/fnupdate-a-row-server-side-data-source)